# How to understand "Dim a, b" without type declaration?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code, I'm trying to figure out what does "F" mean in this code.
`Dim q, F`?

complete code below.

```
Sub TextBox2_Change()
   Dim MySh As Worksheet
   Dim V As Integer, lastrow As Integer
   Dim M As String
   Dim q, F

   On Error Resume Next

   M = TextBox2.Value

   Set MySh = Sheets("db")

   With MySh
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
       Set q = .Range("b4:b" & lastrow).Find(M, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)

       If Not q Is Nothing Then
           F = q.Address

           Do               
               If Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(M, q, 0) = 1 Then
                   ListBox1.AddItem q.Value

                   ListBox1.List(V, 1) = q.Offset(0, 0).Value
                   ListBox1.List(V, 0) = q.Offset(0, -1).Value

                   V = V + 1
               End If

               Set q = .Range("b4:b" & lastrow).FindNext(q)
           Loop While Not q Is Nothing And q.Address <> F
       End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: F seems to represent the address of q in your case, with q being a range (cell). As F variable isn't declared as a type it will be automatically assigned the Variant type

Comment: `Dim q, F` is declaring both `q` and `F` as `variant`. It looks like the value is then being set as a `String` (the address of q which is being set as a `Range`. It would be better in your code to declare both instead of them defaulting to `variant` - `Dim q as Range` and `Dim F as String`

Comment: `Dim q, F` is equivalent to `Dim q as Variant, F as Variant`. You should avoid such "guessing" by Excel, if you know the desired data type, and write e. g. `Dim q as Range, F as String` instead.

Comment: In addition I recommend never to use single letter variables. Instead always use meaningful variables. This makes it much easier to understand and maintain the code and therefore results in less errors. • Example rename `q` to `FoundAt` or  `M` to `SearchFor` or `F` to `FoundAtPreviousAddress`.

Comment: Also you should remove `On Error Resume Next` and fix the errors instead of hiding them **all**: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling) • Finally row counting variables must be declared as `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: `Dim V As Long, LastRow As Long`.